# Shorten code using Ternary Operators

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

How would one shorten the following using ternary operators?

```
if ((pos - maxPos) == (c.clientWidth)) {
    $j("#next").addClass("filter");
} else {
    $j("#next").removeClass("filter");
}
```

Comment: Just because a ternary statement is less code doesn't make it more desirable (or "better"). Condsider others who may need to maintain your code for whom *if..else* may be clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use a ternary operator, [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) accepts a second argument to determine if the class should be added or removed:

```
$j('#next').toggleClass('filter', ((pos - maxPos) == c.clientWidth))
```

However, for the sake of answering your question exactly like you asked (don't use it!):

```
$j('#next')[((pos - maxPos) == c.clientWidth) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('filter');
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better than a ternary, using the `switch` param in `toggleClass()`

```
$j("#next").toggleClass("filter", pos - maxPos === c.clientWidth);
```